# Is it possible that the keyboard opens up automatically as soon as the view appears?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uikeyboard

I have two view controllers,the 1st IC has a button.
when I press on the button the 2nd IC get push on the view.
The 2nd IC has a search bar.

Question:

Is it possible that the keyboard opens up automatically as soon as the 2nd interface controller gets pushed into the view

Here's a link to my project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5jqwv9vfrtlbh9f/AACOAWy-OAqFTJGgDCYsy-xra?dl=0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for the view controller that contains the searchBar:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Edited to be in Swift

Edit 2:
In looking at your project, you can determine that the searchBar is not ready to be first responder by calling `searchBar.canBecomeFirstResponder()` in the `viewDidAppear()` function. I have not dug deep enough to know exactly when the searchBar is able to be first responder, but you can work around this using a NSTimer:

```
func showKeyboard() {
    self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("showKeyboard"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it's not working. I want the keyboard to open up automatically.

Comment: I guess I'm not fully understanding. Can you provide a portion of your code?

Comment: @AziCode Are you using a search controller? If not, just call `becomeFirstResponder` directly on the search bar you have added to the view.

Comment: @Joe The question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C. It's best to post answers in the appropriate language.

Comment: Yes I'm using a search controller . Here's a link to my project if it can help : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5jqwv9vfrtlbh9f/AACOAWy-OAqFTJGgDCYsy-xra?dl=0

Comment: @AziCode Check if my second edit above works for you.